# Adding onto an array to input new information based on user input

Tags: java, arrays, insertion

This is for AP Computer Science. I've got this situation where I need to insert into an array, but to do that I need to increase the storage space in the array. Just curious as to how to pull this off, and why the curriculum didn't just use an ArrayList!

```
public class MainClass 
{  
    public static PhoneExtension[] extensions = new PhoneExtension[]  
        { 
            new PhoneExtension( "Janice", "464" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Peter", "760" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Nicholas", "762" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Michael", "465" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Ryan", "564" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Pamela", "467" ), 
            new PhoneExtension( "Christine", "763" ) 
        }; 

    public static void printDirectory() 
    { 
        for ( PhoneExtension ext : extensions ) 
            System.out.println( ext ); 
    } 

    //My code
    public static void newExtension( String name, String extension, int index ) 
    { 
        if( 0 <= index && 0 <= extensions.length )
        {
            int i;
            for( i = 7 ; i > index ; i-- )
            {
                extensions[i+1]=extensions[i];
            }
            PhoneExtension x = new PhoneExtension( name, extension );
            extensions[index]= x;
        }
    } 

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    { 
        //New inputs and execution
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java
You'd have to ask your professor why they didn't use an ArrayList, but probably, they're starting you off with the simplest structure.

Comment: probably need to pass in the original array -> create a new array of length original array + 1. Copy across the contents of the original array and add the new string to the last element.

Comment: arrays are fixed size upon creation. Create a new larger one, copy contents. See :`System.arraycopy()`

Comment: so what is your question?  If you are asking why the curriculum choose not to use ArrayList, I don't think anyone here can answer you unless he is your lecturer.

Comment: Wouldn't `extensions[extensions.length] = new PhoneExtension(n, e)` add onto the array?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Professor? "AP" is by definition a high school class.

Comment: @AdiInbar *shrug* I'm not familiar with whatever school system that is

Comment: @piticent123, nope, array index out of bounds exception. Arrays are fixed length from `0` to `length-1`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard oh well. Haven't worked with arrays in quite a bit. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks, finally figured it out with your help. Its an online course and we learned arrays 200 pages ago. It was weird they brought them back.