# Changing size of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to change the size of a String array, but I don't know what else to try and this method isn't working. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] names;
        names = new String[5];
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
            addToArray(names, i, "blah");
        }
        System.out.println(names.length);
        System.out.println("bye");
    }

    public static void addToArray(String[] names, int i, String name){
        if (i < names.length){
            names[i] = name;
        }
        else {
            String[] temp;
            temp = new String[names.length + 10];
            System.arraycopy(names, 0, temp, 0, names.length);
            addToArray(temp, i, name);
            names = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run it, it prints that the final length of my array is 5, when it should say 15.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java)

Comment: @user2310289 nope. I looked at that, my effort uses the suggested System.arraycopy. I wasn't very specific with my problem, but when I print the length of the array it is 5, and I expect it to be 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you can't change the reference of any of your (`Object`) method arguments, so...

```
names = temp;
```

Only changes the reference of the `names` variable within the context of the `addToArray` method.  You should use a `return` statement instead...

```
public static String[] addToArray(String[] names, int i, String name){
    if (i < names.length){
        names[i] = name;
    }
    else {
        String[] temp;
        temp = new String[names.length + 10];
        System.arraycopy(names, 0, temp, 0, names.length);
        names = addToArray(temp, i, name);
    }
    return names;
}
```

Don't forget to maintain the reference once the method returns...

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
    names = addToArray(names, i, "blah");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once an array has been created, the size of that array cannot be changed. An array can hold a fixed amount of objects once created.

An `ArrayList` however is able to change the amount of objects it holds dynamically. A way to initialize a simple `ArrayList` would be:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: He's not changing the size of the existing array, he's creating a new one with a larger size, copies elements into it and then makes that temporary array the new array.  It's just his referencing is a bit off... he needs to use a return.

Comment: While I would always agree, we need more context into why the OP is choosing to dynamically resize arrays manually.  Besides, this is almost exactly what an `ArrayList` does any way, it's just backed by an array which is resized as needed ;)

Comment: I'm doing this manually because I have no experience in Java at all, lol. My main language is Python :p . I'm drawing mostly on my C experience to learn this though.

Comment: @Broseph In that case, the suggestion by Brian is an excellent one, you should take the time to have a read through the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) tutorial - +1 to Brian

Comment: Having the right tools can make a job a lot easier.

Comment: After reading what OP posted in this comment section, I have to agree with MadProgrammer that Brian's suggestion is excellent for the OP. It would eliminate a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Three points

1. Arrays are special objects in java, they have a simple attribute
   named `length` which is `final`.
2. Also you are creating a new array, not re-sizing the original array.
3. you can't change the reference of any of your method arguments

Comment: Well, he's not exactly trying to change the size of the existing array.  He already demonstrated the basic understanding of what you've stated, so he's trying to create a new array and point to it.

Comment: Yes, it's much better.

Answer (score 0):

change the return type as **String[]** and return names in **addToArray()** method and assign names=**addToArray(String[] names, int i, String name)**; in **mainMethod** thus you can maintain the keep tracking with reference when size increases