# How to Change the Size of a Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, processing, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to change the dimensions of a two dimensional array in Processing?

```
int m = 4;
int n = 6;
int [][] nums = new int[2][3]; //right now the array has 2 rows and 3 columns

//code that changes the dimensions of the array to m x n

//setting nums.length and nums[0].length to m and n doesn't work, I tried it already
println(nums.length); //should be 4
println(nums[0].length); //should be 6
```

Here is an exact copy of the question:

Modify 2nd Dimension
Write the following function:

```
void setDim(int[][] x, int m) {}
```

That changes the number of columns in each row of x to m.

Edit: I checked the answer, and the code that goes in the middle is

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++) x[i] = new int[m];
```

can someone explain this?

Comment: no that's AFAIK not possible. one way is to use a List type where you can append things. Processing is normal Java as far as Arrays go so this seems helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, because I took a quiz in my Processing class, and one of the questions was to change the dimensions of the array to m x n, and I didn't get it. When the answers were shown, I didn't get a good look at them to understand how to do it.

Comment: perhaps you are confusing it with ArrayList, see that other Q&A which has great information about this.

Comment: I know the size of an ArrayList can easily be changed by adding an element, but I'm pretty sure it was an array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are wrong :) -- unless it was done by copying, for which there is also an example in that other post.

Comment: Here's an exact copy of the question: 

4. Modify 2nd Dimension
Write the following function:
void setDim(int[][] x, int m) {
}
That changes the number of columns in each row of x to m.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52447/discussion-between-jason-chen-and-antont)

Comment: Jason, I have added some explanation regarding the loop you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change the size of the **same** array. The closest thing you can do is create a new one either with `new` operator and `System.arraycopy()` the data from the old one, or with `Arrays.copyOf()`.

You may also consider using `List` instead of array. The size of `List` can be changed which might suit your task.

Regarding the second part of the question: two-dimentional array is an array of length let's say N, each item of that is an array of some length too. `x[i] = new int[m]` means:

- Creating new `int` array of size `m`;
- Setting reference to it into the `x[i]`;

This is essentially the same - **new arrays being created**, the size is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

No, array length is established when it is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

However, you can use something like [System.arraycopy()]([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object), int, java.lang.Object, int, int)), but in order to use it for two dimensional array I wrote this method that use System.arraycopy() to copy one array to another with the same order of elements:

```
public static void copy2dArray(Object src, Object dest){
     copy(src, 0, 0, dest, 0, 0)
}
private static void copy(Object src, int iSrc, int jSrc,  Object dest, int iDes, int jDest){

     int min=Math.min(src[iSrc].length-jSrc, dest[iDes].length-jDest);
     System.arraycopy(src[iSrc], jSrc, dest[iDes], jDes, min);
     if(min == src[iSrc].length-jSrc){
        iSrc++;
        jSrc=0;
        jDest=min;
        if(iSrc == src.length)
            return;
     }
     else{
         iDest++;
         jDest=0;
         jSrc=min;
         if(iDest == dest.length)
            return;
     }
     copy(src, iSrc, jSrc, dest, iDest, jDest);
 }
```

copy2dArray method will take two dimentional arrays and copy the first into the second with the same elements order,

For example: if this code got executed.

```
int [][] src = {{1, 2},
           {3, 4},
           {5, 6}};

int [][] dest = new int [2][4];

copy2dArray(src, dest);
```

The previous code will make
dest = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6}}