# Resizing a 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have been doing questions in my programming book and came across this question:

> What is the output of the following code?

```
int[][] array = new int[5][6];
int[] x = {1, 2};
array[0] = x;
System.out.println("array[0][1] is " + array[0][1]);
```

The book says the answer is:

> array[0][1] is 2

I learned so far that resizing an array isn't possible.
From what I understand of this problem is that

```
int[][] array = new int[5][6]
```

is creating 5 arrays of 6 elements which would display 0's by default if you displayed it on the console

```
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
```

and now from what I understand is that

```
array[0] = x;
```

is basically resizing the first array which has six elements of 0 into an array with 2 elements: 1 and 2.

What am I not understanding? Is it that

```
array[0] = x;
```

is making it so it's actually just changing the index 0 element and index 1 element of the first array? and keeping index 2,3,4,5 elements as 0's in array[0]?

I found this question [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java) but I don't think it helps me answer this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line

```
array[0] = x;
```

is not resizing the array `array[0]`; it's replacing the array `array[0]` such that `array` is now

```
12
000000
000000
000000
000000
```

The old `array[0]` is now discarded and it will be garbage collected.  Now `array[0]` and `x` refer to the same array object, `{1, 2}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
array[0]=x
```

This line is not resizing the array.Its making array[0] and x refer to same object.
To make your concept more clear i would include a snippet

```
        int[][] array = new int[5][6];
        System.out.println("Initial length");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            System.out.println("length of array["+i+"] is " +array[i].length);

        int[] x = {1, 2};
        array[0] = x;//This line makes array[0] and x to refer to the same object

        System.out.println("After changes made");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            System.out.println("length of array["+i+"] is " +array[i].length);

        System.out.println("array[0][1]= "+array[0][1]);
        //changing the content of object referred by x

        x[0]=3;
        x[1]=6;

        System.out.println("After changing X");
        System.out.println("array[0][0]= "+array[0][0]+" array[0][1]="+array[0][1]);
```

Output

```
Initial length
length of array[0] is 6
length of array[1] is 6
length of array[2] is 6
length of array[3] is 6
length of array[4] is 6

After changes made

length of array[0] is 2
length of array[1] is 6
length of array[2] is 6
length of array[3] is 6
length of array[4] is 6

array[0][1]= 2

After changing content of object referred by x

array[0][0]= 3 array[0][1]=6
```

So you can observe that after `array[0]=x` if you change the content of object referred by x then changes are observed in both the arrays array[0] and x because they are referring to same object.
Hope this helps you.Happy coding!!