# creating an array with string split function in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am working on a String. 
e.g of string -  `Cam01,Cam02,Cam03`

Actually I want to split the string using `,` and add to the String array of length 4.

since there are only 3 items , the last item must be added as string `"False"`.

When i created `String arr[] = s.split(",");`  it creates an array of 3 items. 
So last item i need to add as string `"False"`  and make it array with length 4.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Please show us how you try to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java)

Comment: @user1235389 you might want to look at `Arrays.copyOf()`...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
String str = "Cam01,Cam02,Cam03";
str+= ",False";    
String[] arr = str.split(",");
```

now in your `String` array `arr` you have...

```
arr[0]=Cam01
arr[1]=Cam02
arr[2]=Cam03
arr[3]=False
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, OP indicates that the data is in a consistent, expected format. If this is the case then this solution seems to be the simplest and shortest one presented

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an "Array" of variable size, I suggest using an ArrayList instead, where you can simply add things:

`List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.toList( arr ) );`

This way you will create a new ArrayList on which you can call "add":

`while (myArrayList.size < 4) 
    myArrayList.add("False");
}`

If you really need an array later, you can call `myArrayList.toArray( new String[4] );`. But often it is better to work with Collections/Lists anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The array created with the split function is an array of three elements.

It is not possible to change the size of an array once it is created.

So what you can do is create a new array of size 4. Copy all elements of the first array in this new array and set the value of fourth element of the new array to "false".

If you need to do that here is the code:

```
String[] splittedArray = s.split(",");
String[] newArray = new String[4];  // OR any size you like
System.arraycopy(splittedArray, 0, newArray, 0, splittedArray.length);
Arrays.fill(newArray, splittedArray.length, newArray.length, "False");
```

The `newArray` is the array of size four you are searching.

Note that the size of `newArray` must be greater then the size of the `splittedArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this with an buffer String array

```
String arr[] = new String[4];
String buffer[];
String string = "Cam01,Cam02,Cam03";
buffer = string.split(",");
// Forgot the copy...
System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, arr, 0, buffer.length);
for(int i = buffer.length;i<arr.length;++i) {
    arr[i] = "False";
}
```

Comment: @LanguidSquid why is it complicated? It fills the array with False after the last found value to the end of the array. Also why should it print three null values?