# Java - Define array size later

Tags: java, arrays

So I wanna make an array outside a method so other methods can use it:

```
public int x = 0;
public int[] myIntArray = new int[x];
```

But the x is 0, and is later defined in a method as a number entered by user:

```
x = input.nextInt();
```

But the method has already size 0, so how would I modify (redefine) the array's size? I tried to do it by defining the array in a method, but if I do that, I cannot access the array from another method. I am a beginner and I can't do ArrayList, is it possible to do this?

EDIT: Basically: How do I define the size of an array later?

Comment: why not use arraylist instead? You can convert this list to an array later if you want as array only at later stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java)

Comment: So declare the array _after_ the user has entered its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just declare it where you have it with `public int[] myIntArray;` and then initialize it as soon as you know how big it has to be with `myIntArray = new int[x];`

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Yeah I was trying to mark is as the right answer (green checkmark), but it told me to wait about 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare it but not instantiate with `public int[] myIntArray;`

Later, after your code `x = input.nextInt();`, instantiate the array with `myIntArray = new int[x]` within that method. You should still be able to access the array from other methods

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare it without initializing like:

```
   public int[] myIntArray;
```

then put the value after you got one.

```
 x = input.nextInt();
 myIntArray = new int[x];
```