# Java array assignment multiple values keeping the initial array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way in Java to assign multiple values to an Array in one statment
then later you can still be able to append to the same array other values?

e.g. Having a String array defined already with length of 4

```
String[] kids = new String[4];
```

I would like to assign multiple values (2 values for example) to the array in one statment; maybe something close to the array init

```
kids = {"X", "Y"};
```

or the array redefinition

```
kids = new String[] {"X", "Y"};
```

but without loosing the initial array as later I will need to add to it other values e.g.

```
if(newKid) {
    kids[3] = "Z";
}
```

or there is no way to achieve this and have to assign values one by one

```
kids[0] = "X";
kids[1] = "Y";
if(newKid) {
    kids[3] = "Z";
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the original array, use [`Arrays.copyOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) to copy it before modifying.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this as each time I need to append a new values to the array I will have to do a copy

Comment: You can't resize an array anyway. It's a fixed-size data structure. You *have to* copy the array if you want to append an element.

Comment: I don't need to resize it I know the size in advance as indicated 
e.g. new String[4];
and there are some values that I need to add it using one statement then later other data will be completed according to some conditions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy the array with the initialized values into a larger array:

```
String[] kids = Arrays.copyOf(new String[]{ "x", "y" }, 4);
kids[2] = "z";
```

Alternative copy solution:

```
String[] kids = new String[4];
System.arraycopy(new String[]{"x", "y"}, 0, kids, 0, 2);
kids[2] = "z";
```

Alternatively you could have empty Strings as placeholders:

```
String[] test ={ "x", "y", "", "" };
test[2] = "z";
```

Or you could use a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> kids = new ArrayList<>(4);
Collections.addAll(kids, "x", "y");
kids.add("z");
```

Alternative `List<String>` solution:

```
List<String> kids = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("x", "y"));
kids.add("z");
```

Comment: List<String> kids = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("x", "y"));
kids.add("z");

this is exactly the solution I will do if I had to use List

Answer (score 0):

It's solved here
[Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java)

Btw, you can use Lists so you won't need to resize

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
String[] kids = new String[4];
System.arraycopy(new String[] {"X", "Y"}, 0, kids, 0, 2);
```