# Array won't resize without copyOf()

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that's supposed to grow the size of an array by double once it reaches its capacity

I was trying to find a way to resize it without Arrays.copyOf but rather creating an array that's double the size and storing the original array in the new resized array

**works**

```
this.capacity = this.capacity * 2;
this.theData = Arrays.copyOf(this.theData, this.capacity);
```

**doesn't work**
rather it throws away the first index and replaces it with the new value, without resizing

```
double arrayResize[] = new double[this.capacity*2];
for (int i = 0; i<this.theData.length;i++){
        arrayResize[i] = this.theData[i];
}
```

Comment: [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13197702/995714), [How can I resize array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43499183/995714)

Comment: Your second solution should work, as long as you do assign arrayResize to theData.

Comment: @tgdavies and assign `capacity = 2*capacity` as well.

Comment: Btw, I don't think having the `capacity` field is necessary: it looks like it is equal to the array length, so you may as well just use the array length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize an Array while keeping current elements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197702/resize-an-array-while-keeping-current-elements-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot resize an array in Java. Use ArrayList or LinkedList instead.

If you need to have a list for a primitive types and you don't want to wrap them into objects, take a look on Colt or Parallel Colt libraries.