# Designing a generic class that stores comparables in an array

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to figure out how to store the values of tst.insert() and tsttxt.insert() into an array. So far the only thing I have been able to do is have the program recognize that they are there. When I try to print the variables I get the last value of tst.insert(). I am assuming that the last value is displayed because the other values are being overridden.

```
public class genericdrive {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    collection<Integer> tst = new collection<>();
    collection<String> tsttxt = new collection<>();
    //System.out.println("If collection is empty return true: " + tst.isEmpty());
    tst.insert(45);
    tst.insert(43);
    tst.insert(90);
    tsttxt.insert("Jeff");
    tsttxt.insert("Rey");
  }
}
```

..

```
public class collection<T> extends genericdrive {
private T element;
private T[]array;
// collection<T> objt = new collection<>();

public void set(T element) {
    this.element = element;
}

public T get() {
    return element;
}

public <T> void insert(T i) {
    i = (T) element;
    //array[0]=<T> i;
}

}
```

Comment: I though Java class name convention is to start it with the upper letter?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `insert(T i)` *effectively* does nothing. If you want to store the results, use an `ArrayList`, or some form of collection to house the items. Also, why are you extending genericdrive when it has nothing to be inherited?

Comment: There are multiple errors with your code: (1) Capital first letters for class names. (2) Why should `collection` extend `genericdrive`, when it only has a `main` method? (3) `insert` method sets its input?!

Comment: @Zachary I was asked not to use an arrayList. I was trying a few things and forgot to take it out when posting this

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena Remember that arrays have a fixed size when declared. In this case you never instantiate the array, but even if you had you would need to increase the size if you attempt to insert beyond the initial declared size.

Comment: @Zachary I want to set the size of arrays = to the number of inputs (by this I mean the number is tst.insert's and tsttxt.inserts) how would I approach this? I know .length and .size wont work what other ways are there?

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena check the MyCollection class posted in the answer. It dynamically converts generic arrayLists to generic arrays to help suit your purpose. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you want to grow, you could use use `Arrays.copy(T[] array, int length)` if you can use the Arrays class. Otherwise you could simply implement your own method as the `Arrays` class does using `System.arraycopy(...)`

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu The use of `ArrayList` violates the restriction he mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena check the edited post. I have not used ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering that `array` variable holds all the elements the insert function you wrote does not push any value into it.

It is a workaround if the private variable is expected to be an array.

Try the following:

```
public class MyCollection<T> {
  private T element;
  private T[] array;

  MyCollection(){
     array = (T[]) Array.newInstance( Comparable.class , 0); 
  }

  public void set(T element) {
     this.element = element;
  }

  public T get() {
    return element;
  }

  public void insert(T i) {


     T[] temp = (T[])  Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length + 1);
     temp[array.length] = i;
     System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, array.length);
     array = temp;
  }

}
```

Comment: I was asked not to use array list. Is there a way to insert elements into an array?

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena Resizing array is a different problem already discussed  [outside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13197702/4454454) this question

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena check the edited post. No ArrayLists have been used.