# Return value of string 3

Tags: android

I want to return the value of choice in `String prodName[]` but I always got the value of choice is always null please help sorry for my bad English.

[image]

```
String prodName[]={choice};
int Quantity[] = {};
int Total[]={};
String Price[]={choice} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> badapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                                              this,
                                              R.array.products,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    badapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(badapter);


    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, prodName, Price);
    //set the adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sample;

            choice = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            prodName = choice.split(choice);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i got the value of spinner in choice but when i put it on string prodName i cant get the value it give me always a null

Comment: I believe your problem is related to your use of the java array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13197760/8560690

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using `split()` method in the wrong way.

```
String demo = "1,2,3,4";
String[] splitted = demo.split(",");  //splitted will be an array containing 4 elements [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now I guess you know what the `split()` method does. :)

Since you already got the selected item text as String in the variable `choice`. why are you calling `split()` method on it?

You can find more about the `split()` method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Try below way to initialise array

```
String[] prodName={choice};
```